# Is it possible to modify file content when loading/saving to/from Eclipse editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to create an eclipse plugin that does the following:

1. Upon file open - modify the loaded content slightly and load the modified content to the editor.
2. Upon file save - modify the saved content slightly and save the modified content to the file.

Can this be done? I hope I'm asking an ok question. I am new to eclipse plugins and this can realy save me alot of time.

Comment: What is it you want to do?  There might be another way to do it than to write a plugin.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I want to change the code style upon load to my own style, and change it back to the original style when saving.

Comment: You can set up Save Actions to run when a file is saved (at least for the Java editor). I don't know of anything that runs during loading.

Comment: Maybe you can implement your own [Eclipse File System (EFS)](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EFS) as virtual view on the "real" files.

Comment: @EladWeiss To be frank I would recommend against this, because I do not understand how you will change the code style back to the one you do not like.  Instead either learn to love the one everybody else uses (which in the long run will save you a _lot_ of pain), or consider using IntelliJ where the editor can present the code differently than written (named parameters, anonymous classes as lambdas etc).